# How to use Elasticsearch rollover API where alias is updated to point to the latest created index?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a Logstash pipeline that runs on a daily schedule and pushes data to Elasticsearch using `agent_index_%{+YYYY_MM_dd}` index signature. So every day I would get a new index created eg: agent_index_2020_05_05 for 5th May 2020 and agent_index_2020_05_06 for 6th May 2020.

For this agent index alias is updated using it's mapping, which works fine, but my requirement is that the agent alias should always point to only 1 index that is the latest index.

mapping

```
PUT /_template/agent_template
{
  "order": 0,
  "index_patterns": [
    "agent_index_*"
  ],
  "aliases": {
    "agent": {}
  }
}
```

I looked into [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/indices-rollover-index.html), but looks like the index name must end in incremental numbers.

```
POST /agent/_rollover?dry_run
{
  "conditions": {
    "max_age": "1d"
  }
}
```

Error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "index name [agent_index_2020_05_06] does not match pattern '^.*-\\d+$'"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "index name [agent_index_2020_05_06] does not match pattern '^.*-\\d+$'"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Is there a way to use elasticsearch rollover API to only allow the latest created index to be updated in the alias, that means at a given point alias points to only one index which is the latest index?

Note: Using Elasticsearh v6.2.4

**Update**

My Logstash configuration

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "ojdbc7.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class    => "Java::oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@EDM:1521/aba"
        jdbc_user => "read"
        jdbc_password => "read"
        schedule => "50 6 * * *"
        statement_filepath =>"agent.sql"
       }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:17002"
        index => "agent_index_%{+YYYY_MM_dd}"
        document_type => "agent"
    }
}
```

**Update**

Using [monitoring API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/node-stats-api.html#event-stats) to get details as suggested by @Val, but everytime I run `curl -XGET "localhost:15050/_node/stats/events?pretty"` I get different IN count. Please check screenshot below. So how do I determine if total events are fetched?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES 6.2, the rollover API requires that the index name ends with a sequence number, such as `-00001`. However, if this is not the case, then it is also possible to use a different index name but you need to [specify it explicitly](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-rollover-index.html#_naming_the_new_index) in the rollover call, like this:

```
POST /agent/_rollover/agent_index_2020_05_13
{
  "conditions": {
    "max_age": "1d"
  }
}
```

So if the index pointed by the alias `agent` is older than one day, a new index called `agent_index_2020_05_13` will be created by the rollover call.

**Note:** However, since ES 6.2.4 is [EOL](https://www.elastic.co/support/eol), you should upgrade your stack to at least 6.6, then you get [ILM support](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) in Logstash for free and it will take care of setting everything up properly in ES.

Comment: how do I do this in Logstash? I have updated my question with my Logstash configuration.

Comment: So this configuration is scheduled to run every day at 6:50 am. It creates and associates the newly created index with the `agent` alias, and at any given point of time I want only one index, that is the latest one to be associated with `agent` alias type. Can it be achieved using your solution?

Comment: No, as I mentioned, if you want to benefit from the ILM feature to do this for you automatically, you should upgrade to at least ES/Logstash 6.6. Otherwise, you can set up a cron job that calls the `_rollover` endpoint everyday, that would do the trick

Comment: is there any API in Logstash which can tell us that a particular load is totally complete? At present some loads take around 15-20 minutes and I validate the completion state by comparing the count between my source DB and ES index. So only after this, I will run command for rollover or to de associate an index from an alias

Comment: Using the [monitoring APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/node-stats-api.html#event-stats) you can see how many events got in and out. If the two numbers are identical and stable, it means the load has finished, otherwise it is still in progress.

Comment: when I run `GET /_node/stats/events?pretty` in Kibana I get  index_not_found_exception  `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_expression","resource.id":"_node","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"_node"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_expression","resource.id":"_node","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"_node"},"status":404}`. 

If I replace `_node` with `agent_index_2020_05_13` it gives `{"_index":"agent_index_2020_05_13","_type":"stats","_id":"events","found":false}`

Comment: You need to hit Logstash on port 9600 (default), not Elasticsearch as that's a monitoring API that gives you insights into the Logstash pipeline processing.

Comment: I updated my question with details. The IN  counts are different every time I hit the monitoring API. Data has millions of records.

Comment: That's what you would expect while something is being loaded. You need to check those numbers between two or three different runs at regular intervals (say each 15s)

Comment: So there is no straight way using an API call to check whether a load is complete or not or get the total count that was fetched by the SQL query? Instead, I should compare IN and OUT values every 15s and if the value matches and there is no change for 3 consecutive checks in the IN value I should conclude the load successfully complete?

Comment: Logstash runs continuously and has no idea of what "a load is complete" means... From its perspective, it can receive data anytime, it processes it and sends it away... All you can do is observe it and take action based on what you see.